# C: Can't get the correct output I need

Tags: c

EDIT: New Problem, now I get a totally different output than the one I need. The following is how I have it written, assignment instruction is on the bottom, please and thank you all!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main() {

   FILE * ifp = NULL;
   char filename[20];
        printf("What is the name of the input file?\n");
        scanf(" %s", &filename);

   while (ifp == NULL){

        /*PROMPT USER FOR INPUT FILENAME*/
        printf("What is the name of the input file?\n");
        scanf(" %s", &filename);

        /*OPEN INPUT FILE*/
        ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
        }

   int totalSize = 0;
          fscanf(ifp, "%d",  &totalSize);

   int id[totalSize];
   char category[totalSize];
   int handCombatPt[totalSize];
   int distCombatPt[totalSize];
   int observationPt[totalSize];
   int concealPt[totalSize];
   int agilityPt[totalSize];
   float ranking[totalSize];

   int row=0;
   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       fscanf(ifp, "%d %c %d %d %d %d %d\n", id+row, category+row, handCombatPt+row, distCombatPt+row, observationPt+row, concealPt+row, agilityPt+row);
   }

   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       if (category[row] == 'A') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row] + distCombatPt[row]*2 + observationPt[row]*2 + concealPt[row] + agilityPt[row]*5)/10.0;
       }
       if (category[row] == 'C') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row]*5 + distCombatPt[row]*5 + observationPt[row] + concealPt[row] + agilityPt[row]*2)/10.0;
       }
       if (category[row] == 'S') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row] + distCombatPt[row] + observationPt[row]*5 + concealPt[row]*5 + agilityPt[row]*2)/10.0;
       }
   }

   int firstA, firstS, secondS, firstC, secondC;

   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       if (category[row]=='A' && ranking[firstA] < ranking[row]) {
           firstA = row;

       }

       if (category[row]=='S' && ranking[firstS] < ranking[row]) {
           secondS = firstS;
           firstS = row;

       }
       else if (category[row]=='S' && ranking[secondS] < ranking[row]) {
           secondS = row;

       }

       if (category[row]=='C' && ranking[firstC] < ranking[row]) {
           secondC = firstC;
           firstC = row;

       }
       else if (category[row]=='C' && ranking[secondC] < ranking[row]) {
           secondC = row;

       }
   }

   printf("A : %d %f \n", id[firstA], ranking[firstA]);
   printf("C : %d %f \n", id[firstC], ranking[firstC]);
   printf("C : %d %f \n", id[secondC], ranking[secondC]);
   printf("S : %d %f \n", id[firstS], ranking[firstS]);
   printf("S : %d %f \n", id[secondS], ranking[secondS]);

return 0;
}
```

And here's the input.txt file:

```
10
14 A 447 252 68 34 978
2 C 230 299 597 180 9
27 A 318 220 97 28 1317
32 C 563 450 547 112 28
8 C 669 260 200 36 171
11 S 179 45 1342 732 174
19 S 74 249 861 1165  6 
21 A 757 240 97 119 2032
15 S 275 177 588 577 52
6 C 886 401 327 109 48
```

The program needs to output the follow:

```
A: 21 1171.00
C: 6 696.70
C: 32 578.00
S: 11 1094.20
S: 19 1046.50
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the assignment in case it helps anyone understand what I'm trying to do

Problem: Mentorship 
It is time for your friend to select their ninja mentors! Ninja students are able to select several mentorsfrom the class of higher level students to learn special skills from. Skills are categorized as Stealth (S),Combat (C), and Agility (A). Your friend will be provided with a file of older students that has their nameand rankings for the different skills. They can then choose 5 mentors to learn from. To assist, your program should read in all of the student’s information and print out the two bestcombat mentors, the two best stealth mentors, and the best agility mentor. If your friend has been adiligent student, they will be able to select these best options! If not, they will need to go down the listand select other mentors.Combat Skills are split into Hand to Hand and Distance. Stealth skills are split into Observation andConcealment. Agility is a singular category.

Input File Format
The first line of the input file will contain a single integer n (5 ≤ n ≤ 100), denoting the number ofpotential mentors, for which information is listed in the file. The following n lines will have all theinformation for all the mentors with one mentor's information on a single line. Each line will have thefollowing format:ID Category HandCombatPts DistanceCombatPts ObservationPts ConcealPts AgilityPtsID will be a positive integer representing the potential mentor.
Category will be a single character, either 'C', 'S' or 'A', for combat, stealth or agility, respectively.HandCombatPts will be an integer representing the number of points that student was given last year bytheir hand to hand combat instructor. DistanceCombatPts will be an integer representing the number of points that student was given lastyear by their distance combat instructor.ObservationPts will be an integer representing the number of points that student was given last year by

their observation and spying skills instructor.

ConcealPts will be an integer representing the number of points that student was given last year by their

concealment and disguise instructor.
AgilityPts will be an integer representing the number of points that student was given last year by theiragility and acrobatics instructor.

How to Compute a Ranking
For each potential mentor, their ranking will be a summation weighted by their category. If they are a potential combat mentor their ranking should be:(HandCombatPts*5 + DistanceCombatPts*5 + ObservationPts + ConcealPts + AgilityPts*2)/10If they are a potential stealth mentor their ranking should be:(HandCombatPts + DistanceCombatPts + ObservationPts*5 + ConcealPts*5 + AgilityPts*2)/10If they are a potential agility mentor their ranking should be:(HandCombatPts + DistanceCombatPts*2 + ObservationPts*2 + ConcealPts + AgilityPts*5)/10

Program Specification
You must use arrays to solve the problem.
Your program should first prompt the user for the name of the input file. Then, your programshould process the input file and write the five best mentors for your friend. Each line shouldlist the category, the ID, and the ranking of the mentor, respectively, separated by spaces.Round the ranking to two decimal places. The mentors must be listed according to category asfollows: agility, followed by the two combat, followed by the two stealth. Both the combat andthe stealth mentors must be listed in descending order of ranking.

Comment: You don't check whether you successfully opened the file before you try using it.  The chances are, you didn't open the file successfully, so the program crashes, giving you the error you see.

Comment: Check the return value of fopen(...).  If ifp is NULL you should exit with an error and tell the user you couldn't open the input file.

Comment: Why C++ tag? It is not C++ compliant code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I haven't finished writing, but yes, I am adding that part. I know that input.txt is in the same folder as the .c file, and I opened the file and made sure it opened. So even when I put in the right file name it still crashes

Comment: Don't put incomplete programs on SO — they'll be shredded mercilessly.  What you put on SO should be an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You have to demonstrate that you've avoided silly mistakes somehow (and not checking whether `fopen()` works is extremely silly — don't submit code on SO without that check!).

Comment: And don't use uninitialized variables — they'll bite you, every time.  Well, nearly every time.  And they'll definitely bite whenever it matters (e.g. when the code works for you but crashes for your teacher or the online judge or your manager).  `int firstA, firstS, secondS, firstC, secondC;` — uninitialized variables galore — 

   `for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       if (category[row]=='A' && ranking[firstA] < ranking[row]) {` — oops, `firstA` is uninitialized; you've no idea which row it is accessing.

Comment: Ok I editted it with that part. It works as intended to keep asking for the file when I put the wrong file name in, but when i put the right file name in it crashes.

Comment: On the whole, it would be better to exit with an error message than reprompt, but that's your design decision.  If you do reprompt, make sure you put an upper bound on the number of times you're willing to retry — 10 is usually plenty.

Comment: It opens now, after I set the uninitialized variables to 0, but now I get a completely different output then the one I need. It turns this:

A : 10821168 0.000000
C : 10821168 0.000000
C : 10821168 0.000000
S : 10821168 0.000000
S : 10821168 0.000000

I must have done something wrong in the initialization

Comment: I editted my post with the assignment instructions in case that helps anyone understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you for the help thus far though made some progress :)

Comment: Show the code that prints out the data the program just read.  This is the most basic debugging technique — and also very effective.  You should be checking that the `fscanf()` returns 7 each time; there's a data problem if it does not.  The trailing newline in the format string is OK (though not really necessary) when the input comes from a file, but it's very bad news if the user is expected to type the input.  Simply omit it.  If the first field on the line is processed by `%c` (which doesn't skip white space), put a space in the format string before the `%c`.

Comment: And you've still not initialized the variables!

Answer (score 0):

First:

'Program compiles but then “program.exe has stopped working'

I'm sorry to have to inform you that this is the usual behaviour.  Writing code and getting it to compile is trivial compared with the effort and skill required to get it to do what you want.  Testing and debugging is 99% of software development skill.  That is why debuggers exist.

Next:

ALWAYS check the result of ALL system calls.  In your case, specifically fopen().

...............

[sigh] 'after I set the uninitialized variables to 0, but now I get a completely different output then the one I need'

See above, especially the hint: 'That is why debuggers exist'.  It is really MUCH easier for you to fix your problems than to use SO contributors remote-debug by text exchange.  You have the actual code, (ie. not what you originally posetd), the environment, test files etc.  We have what you are drip-feeding us, both in terms of what you are doing and what you are getting:(

You must learn to debug now, before you write even one more line of code.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop programs and should not try:(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is claimed that the file is opened successfully, and the revised code sits in a loop until a file is opened successfully (or the user gets bored and terminates the program — let's hope the user doesn't indicate EOF!).  The problem probably occurs later — with the uninitialized variables.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to C programming, and I don't really understand what a debugger is, I see the tab in codeblocks. I put the assignment instructions in my editted post in case that helps. Or if you can point me in the right direction to how to use a debugger? Thank you for your help thus far ive made some progress

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Hey thanks guys for the help, I don't know what the hell happened, after I restarted my computer and cleaned up the code a bit now it works. I am still interested in what the debugging means though?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main() {

   FILE * ifp = NULL;
   char filename[20];

    while (ifp == NULL){


        printf("What is the name of the input file?\n");
        scanf(" %s", &filename);

        ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
        }


   int totalSize = 0;
          fscanf(ifp, "%d",  &totalSize);

   int id[totalSize];
   char category[totalSize];
   int handCombatPt[totalSize];
   int distCombatPt[totalSize];
   int observationPt[totalSize];
   int concealPt[totalSize];
   int agilityPt[totalSize];
   float ranking[totalSize];

   int row=0;
   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       fscanf(ifp, "%d %c %d %d %d %d %d\n", id+row, category+row, handCombatPt+row, distCombatPt+row, observationPt+row, concealPt+row, agilityPt+row);
   }

   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       if (category[row] == 'A') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row] + distCombatPt[row]*2 + observationPt[row]*2 + concealPt[row] + agilityPt[row]*5)/10.0;
       }
       if (category[row] == 'C') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row]*5 + distCombatPt[row]*5 + observationPt[row] + concealPt[row] + agilityPt[row]*2)/10.0;
       }
       if (category[row] == 'S') {
           ranking[row] = (handCombatPt[row] + distCombatPt[row] + observationPt[row]*5 + concealPt[row]*5 + agilityPt[row]*2)/10.0;
       }
   }

   int firstA=0, firstS=0, secondS=0, firstC=0, secondC=0;

   for (row=0; row<totalSize; row++) {
       if (category[row]=='A' && ranking[firstA] < ranking[row]) {
           firstA = row;

       }

       if (category[row]=='S' && ranking[firstS] < ranking[row]) {
           secondS = firstS;
           firstS = row;

       }
       else if (category[row]=='S' && ranking[secondS] < ranking[row]) {
           secondS = row;

       }

       if (category[row]=='C' && ranking[firstC] < ranking[row]) {
           secondC = firstC;
           firstC = row;

       }
       else if (category[row]=='C' && ranking[secondC] < ranking[row]) {
           secondC = row;

       }
   }

   printf("A : %d %f \n", id[firstA], ranking[firstA]);
   printf("C : %d %f \n", id[firstC], ranking[firstC]);
   printf("C : %d %f \n", id[secondC], ranking[secondC]);
   printf("S : %d %f \n", id[firstS], ranking[firstS]);
   printf("S : %d %f \n", id[secondS], ranking[secondS]);

return 0;
}
```

This worked, I initialized everything to 0 and made a while loop for the file name, now it outputs corerctly, though more numbers after the decimal than I need but I think i can fix it with a .lf in the variable print part. If anyone can check that and let me know if they see any thing wrong with it please. Thank you all for the help!